# React handling click outside for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to mimic a header where if you click a dropdown menu, it will display the popup menu and upon clicking outside of the popup menu element, it'll disappear for multiple elements in the header.

Here's a vanilla pen that I modified but could not manage to get it working:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JOGGzL

```
handleClick() {
    if (!this.state.popupVisible) {
      document.addEventListener('click', this.handleOutsideClick, false);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleOutsideClick, false);
    }

    this.setState(prevState => ({
       popupVisible: !prevState.popupVisible,
    }));
}

handleOutsideClick(e) {
    if (this.node.contains(e.target)) {
      return;
    }

    this.handleClick();
}
```

I've tried creating unique refs and passing in a parameter through handleClick and handleOutsideClick to differentiate between the two different popup buttons, but I'm running into an issue where it seems to be spawning a lot of EventListeners without removing them correctly.

What would be the most elegant way to toggle either one button at a time and deactivating all if the user clicks outside either popup elements? Would I have to create separate Components to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Your example seems to be working fine. What is your example doing/not doing that you want?

Comment: I think people are missing the section that I mention that I want it to toggle only one button at a time.

Comment: what does that mean? What is "it"? Toggle what? What does toggle do?

Answer (score 1):

Rather then adding and removing the event in the actual handler, you could use react's lifecycle methods:

```
componentDidMount() {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.handleOutsideClick);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleOutsideClick);
}
```

Your handleOnClick method could do the standard toggle state stuff, but then handleOutsideClick could just always set it to false if its not the dropdown or contains the target:

```
handleOutsideClick(event) {
    if (this.node === event.target || !this.node.contains(event.target)) {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
             popupVisible: false
        }));
    }
}
```

The most elegant way to handle multiple pop ups would be to have a class that does all the logic you see above called Popover that renders a child component. You could reuse it in a parent component like this:

```
const MorePops = () => (
    <div>
        <Popover label={'label text'}>
            <div>{'Child'}</div>
        </Popover>
        <Popover label={'label text'}>
            <div>{'Child'}</div>
        </Popover>
        <Popover label={'label text'}>
            <div>{'Child'}</div>
        </Popover>
        <Popover label={'label text'}>
            <div>{'Child'}</div>
        </Popover>
    </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want the popovers to be toggled independently from each other. The fastest way to do it is to move the popover to separate component.

```
class Popover extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
    super();

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.handleOutsideClick = this.handleOutsideClick.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      popupVisible: false
    };
  }

  handleClick() {
    if (!this.state.popupVisible) {
      // attach/remove event handler
      document.addEventListener('click', this.handleOutsideClick, false);
    } else {
      document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleOutsideClick, false);
    }

    this.setState(prevState => ({
       popupVisible: !prevState.popupVisible,
    }));
  }

  handleOutsideClick(e) {
    // ignore clicks on the component itself
    if (this.node.contains(e.target)) {
      return;
    }

    this.handleClick();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="popover-container" ref={node => {this.node=node; }}>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
          Toggle Popover
        </button>
        { this.state.popupVisible && <div className="popover">I'm a popover!</div> }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And here's your root component

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Popover/>
        <Popover/>
      </div>
    );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('App'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add removing all popups in the componentdidmount lifecycle method and remove the handleoutsideclick method:

```
componentDidMount() {
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target);
  if ([].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.popover-container button')).indexOf(e.target) === -1) {
        this.setState({
          popupVisible: false,
         });
       return;
     }
   }, true);
 }
```

Check this pen: https://codepen.io/Marouen/pen/vWLKKK

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a tiny component (466 Byte gzipped) that already exists for this functionality then you can check out this library [react-outclick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-outclick). It lets you detect events outside of a component/element.

The good thing about the library is that it also lets you detect clicks outside of a component and inside of another (required for nested popups and modals). It also supports detecting other types of events.